# How do I retrieve image from Informix and Oracle database in Python?

Tags: python, oracle, blob, informix

I am writing a python script to get image data (blob) from Informix/Oracle database and upload images to AWS S3. Part of my code is as below:

```
try:
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute(sql)

    for row in cur:
        client = trim(row[0])
        date = trim(row[1])
        filename = trim(row[2])
        imageblob = row[3].read()
        write_file(filename, imageblob)
```

I got the following error (Informix case):

```
Error: <class '_informixdb.InterfaceError'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "UploadImagesToS3.py", line 57, in getImageFromDB
    imageblob = row[3].read()
InterfaceError: Sblob is not open
```

Could anyone give a help? The code needs to be compatible with both Informix and Oracle DB. Thanks

Comment: Can you use Jython? For operations on databases I prefer Jython because it can work with JDBC drivers and does not need other client software.

Comment: For best performance with Oracle, review the use of an OutputTypeHandler: https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/lob_data.html#fetching-lobs-as-strings-and-bytes